# maven-plugin-plugin:3.2:descriptor failed: 52264, but only for one project

Tags: maven-3, maven-plugin

For my project I want to extent mavens abilities by adding custom plugins.

I created a parent POM for all my maven plugins. Then I created two plugings using this parent pom.

The problem is: one of them is successfully build by maven,

```
[INFO] --- maven-plugin-plugin:3.2:descriptor (default-descriptor) @ VersionSplitter-maven-plugin ---
[INFO] Using 'Cp1252' encoding to read mojo metadata.
[INFO] Applying mojo extractor for language: java
[INFO] Mojo extractor for language: java found 0 mojo descriptors.
[INFO] Applying mojo extractor for language: bsh
[INFO] Mojo extractor for language: bsh found 0 mojo descriptors.
[INFO] Applying mojo extractor for language: java-annotations
[INFO] Mojo extractor for language: java-annotations found 1 mojo descriptors.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ VersionSplitter-maven-plugin ---
```

but the other one fails with:

```
[INFO] --- maven-plugin-plugin:3.2:descriptor (default-descriptor) @ FileSize-Plugin ---
[INFO] Using 'Cp1252' encoding to read mojo metadata.
[INFO] Applying mojo extractor for language: java
[INFO] Mojo extractor for language: java found 0 mojo descriptors.
[INFO] Applying mojo extractor for language: bsh
[INFO] Mojo extractor for language: bsh found 0 mojo descriptors.
[INFO] Applying mojo extractor for language: java-annotations
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.481 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-11-24T11:44:57+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugin-plugin:3.2:descriptor (default-descriptor) on project FileSize-Plugin: Execution default-descriptor of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugin-plugin:3.2:descriptor failed: 52264 -> [Help 1]
```

It fails as soon as I do something different in `execute()` than calling `getLog()`...

I really do not see the difference between both projects so I don't know what to change to make the failing Project work. Any help is appreciated!

---

## MWSE

### parent POM:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>my.company.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>MavenPluginsParent</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <properties>
    <maven.api.version>3.6.0</maven.api.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>Cp1252</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>Cp1252</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <maven.build.timestamp.format>YYYYMMddHHmm</maven.build.timestamp.format>
    <application.build.version>${maven.build.timestamp}</application.build.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
      <version>${maven.api.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-project</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>${maven.api.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

### project 1  (failing)

#### pom

```xml
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <artifactId>FileSize-Plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>
      <parent>
        <groupId>my.company.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>MavenPluginsParent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
      </parent>
    </project>
```

#### Java class

```java
    import java.io.File;
    import java.util.Optional;
    import java.util.Properties;
    
    import org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractMojo;
    import org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException;
    import org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations.LifecyclePhase;
    import org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations.Mojo;
    import org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations.Parameter;
    import org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject;
    
    @Mojo(name = "FileSize", defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.PREPARE_PACKAGE, requiresProject = true)
    public class FileSizeMojo extends AbstractMojo {
    
        @Parameter(readonly = true, required = true)
        private File targetFile;
    
        @Parameter(defaultValue = "file.size", readonly = true, required = false)
        private String destPropertyName;
    
        @Parameter(defaultValue = "${project}", required = true, readonly = true)
        private MavenProject project;
    
        @Override
        public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException {
           // do something
           String.valueOf(0);
        }
    }
```

### project 2 (working)

#### pom

```xml
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <artifactId>VersionSplitter-Plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>
      <parent>
        <groupId>my.company.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>MavenPluginsParent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
      </parent>
    </project>
```

#### Java Class

```java
    import java.util.Optional;
    import java.util.Properties;
    import java.util.regex.Matcher;
    import java.util.regex.Pattern;
    
    import org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractMojo;
    import org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException;
    import org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations.LifecyclePhase;
    import org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations.Mojo;
    import org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations.Parameter;
    import org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject;
    
    @Mojo(name = "VersionSplitter", defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.INITIALIZE, requiresProject = true)
    public class VersionSplitterMojo extends AbstractMojo {
    
        @Parameter(defaultValue = "${project}", required = true, readonly = true)
        private MavenProject project;
    
        @Override
        public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException {
            // do something
            String.valueOf(0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why using maven-project in version 2.2.1 ???

Comment: it was the latest on mavencentral.

Comment: please try newer version of maven-plugin-plugin 3.7.0

Comment: @SlawomirJaranowski The maven version run on the build server will be 3.6.0, I have no admin access to that. Will that interfere?

Comment: You should replace maven-project with maven-core with minimum level you want to support... in your case I would suggest to use 3.6.0 and related to that to use the same version for maven-plugin-api and as @SlawomirJaranowski suggested you should use maven-plugin-plugin to most recent and also maven-plugin-annotation...

Comment: @khmarbaise changed the dependencies as suggested, but no success...

Comment: Do you have it as an example project on github or alike?

Comment: @khmarbaise https://github.com/tpd-opitz/mojo-build-fail-mcse